# Mixing patterns with string patterns

Tags: pattern-matching

I have imported an XML document into *Mathematica*. It is now represented as Symbolic XML expression in the variable `xml`:

```
XMLObject["Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0"]}, 
 XMLElement[
  "slideshow", {}, {XMLElement["title", {}, {"XML Tutorial"}], 
   XMLElement[
    "slide", {}, {XMLElement["title", {}, {"Agenda"}], 
     XMLElement["item", {}, {"Introduction"}], 
     XMLElement["item", {}, {"XML technologies"}], 
     XMLElement["item", {}, {"Editors for XML documents"}]}]}], {}]
```

Using the `Cases` function I want to extract the `XMLElement` expressions whose plain text contents contain the word "XML":

```
Cases[xml, XMLElement["item", _, {___ ~~ "XML" ~~ ___}], Infinity]
```

This however returns the empty list, probably because it is mixing a *Mathematica* expression pattern with a string expression pattern. How does one go about embedding a string pattern into a regular pattern?

Comment: Not fully related, but I think this a must-read piece of text for anyone matching a `*ML` kind of thing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/353410

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd have used `StringMatchQ[]` if I was in your shoes:

```
xmlDoc = XMLObject[
    "Document"][{XMLObject["Declaration"]["Version" -> "1.0"]}, 
   XMLElement[
    "slideshow", {}, {XMLElement["title", {}, {"XML Tutorial"}], 
     XMLElement[
      "slide", {}, {XMLElement["title", {}, {"Agenda"}], 
       XMLElement["item", {}, {"Introduction"}], 
       XMLElement["item", {}, {"XML technologies"}], 
       XMLElement["item", {}, {"Editors for XML documents"}]}]}], {}];

Cases[xmlDoc, XMLElement["item", _, {s_String /; 
    StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ "XML" ~~ ___]}], Infinity]
```

which yields

```
{XMLElement["item", {}, {"XML technologies"}], 
 XMLElement["item", {}, {"Editors for XML documents"}]}
```

Comment: Also usable:  `test = StringMatchQ[#, "*XML*"] &;    

Cases[xmlDoc, XMLElement["item", _, {s_String?test}], Infinity]`

Comment: Mathematica does not seem to offer an elegant solution in this case.